# TreeView with grouping

Tags: wpf, treeview, grouping

i need to create an overlap for a group in a TreeView

something like so :

[image]

In my ItemsSource Node 1 , Node 1.1 , and Node 2 are grouped together
and Node 3 and Node 3.1 are grouped together

using a CollectionView with a PropertyGroupDesciptor.

Now i wan't to add the Orange Rectangle around each group

My attempts so far was to use GroupStyle but that resulted in 2 Orange GroupItems with the value of the grouping property , what i need is to style the GroupBox for the group

any ideas ?

My Code (This part seems irrelevant to me since it just my grouping logic , but if it's important for some people to understand what iv'e described i gladly placed it here) :

CS :

public class MyNode
   {
        public int GroupProperty
        {
            get;set;
        }

```
    public string Title
    {
        get;set; 
    }

    public List<MyNode> Children
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
```

}

In ViewModel :

```
 public List<MyNode> MyItemsSource
 {
     get
     {
          return new List<MyNode>
          {
               List<MyNode> nodes = new :ist<MyNode>();

               MyNode node1 = new MyNode{ Title = "Node1" ,GroupProperty = 1 }
               node1.Children.Add(new MyNode{ Title = "Node 1.1" , GroupProperty = 1});

               nodes.Add(node1)
               MyNode node2 = new MyNode{ Title = "Node1" ,GroupProperty = 2 }

               nodes.Add(node2)              

               ... same goes for Node 3 and Node 3.1 

               return nodes;
          };

     }

  }
```

XAML :

Resources :

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="protocolTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:MyNode}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="rootTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:MyNode}" 
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource protocolTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubProtocols}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="protocols" Source="{Binding Protocols}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="GroupProperty" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

View :

```
    <TreeView  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource rootTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource protocols}}" />
```

O'k iv'e added the code which Groups my ItemsSource , how do i create the GroupStyle which would place a kind of overlay on the grouped items ?

Comment: Would it not be `ItemsPresenter`? or if you use a style `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: But that is hard to tell if we haven't got any code to go from. Could you post some code of your attempts? So we know what approach you have taken.

Comment: @XAMlMAX The code here is kind of meaningless , i perform a grouping based on some property of my ItemsSource's Type , and i have an HierarchicalDataTemplate for the items , and that's it. 
it's Exactly the drawing with out the Orange Rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer , all i needed to do in The GroupStyle 
was place an ItemsPresenter in my GroupItem Style like so :

```
 <TreeView.GroupStyle>  
            <GroupStyle>                                        
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="Orange"/>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />                                      
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </TreeView.GroupStyle>
```